# Adding text read from a file to an array list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble putting text read from a file into an array list.

My text looks like this:

```
438;MIA;JFK;10:55;1092;447
638;JFK;MIA;19:45;1092;447
689;ATL;DFW;12:50;732;448 etc...
```

My code looks like this:

```
package filesexample;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
*
* @author 
*/
public class FilesExample {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File ("/Schedule.txt");

    try
    {
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(file);;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner= new Scanner(line);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
            while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
            String part = lineScanner.next();
            System.out.print(part + " ");
        }

          System.out.println();          




        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Some help on getting started would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: What exactly from those lines you want to put in `ArrayList`? Any specific part only or the whole line?

Comment: of the text I posted, the first number is flight number, origin, destination, time, miles and price.  They all need to have there own array for each category, so flight number will need its own array, origin its own array etc...

Comment: you print with System.out.print(part + " ");, so just after/before that statement add string to your list. is it hard to see?

Comment: @user: Pretty please ... always tell us exactly where your problem lies ... if you expect people to compile your code, you'll get downvotes, believe me

Comment: @user1824856.. Why exactly you want to have different arrays for them?

Comment: I just need some help on starting the arraylist process, I have imported the file and used the delimiter to split the file but now I need to get each category into there own arraylist so I can access them later

Comment: very sorry for not being so specific, first time asking a question here!

Comment: I am trying to make an airline reservation program, I have multiple text files I need to import and then add them into arraylists so I can go back later to access those arraylists and pick information out of them as needed, or access an entire array

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the following

```
Scanner lineScanner= new Scanner(line);
lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
```

Just do

```
String[] parts = line.split(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

use [String.split(delimiter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split your String.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] strArr = line.split(";");
                for(String s: strArr){
                 list.add(s); //adding a string into the list
                 System.out.println(s +  " ");
                }
                }

              System.out.println();
```

**EDIT: From your comments**

> of the text I posted, the first number is flight number, origin, destination, time, miles and price. They all need to have
>   there own array for each category, so flight number will need its own
>   array, origin its own array etc.

you don't need an array for each property. create a class and name it **Filght**. and make your properties as instance variables.

```
class Flight {
private long filghtNo;
private String origin;
private dest;
private Date time;
private long miles;
private double price;
//setters and getters
}

   List<Flight> list = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    Flight flight = new Flight();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
                if(scan.hasNextLong()){
                 flight.setFilgthNo(scan.nextlong());
                  }
                else if // do the  same for other properties
                }

     list.add(flight);
```

This way is more **Object Oriented**.

Answer (score 0):

> They all need to have there own array for each category, so flight
>   number will need its own array, origin its own array

I would say, don't. You don't need to have separate array for each of them.

I would rather create a `class` with attributes: -`flight number, origin, destination, time, miles and price`.

Now for every line, I would just split it on `;`, and have a constructor in the class that takes an array as parameter. And rather than having separate `ArrayList` for each of those parameters, I would have an `ArrayList` of that class instance.

```
class Flight {
    private int flightNumber;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    ... so on for `time, miles and price`

    public Flight(String[] attr) {
        this.flightNumber = Integer.parseInt(attr[0]);
        this.origin = attr[1];
        this.destination = attr[2];
        ... so on.
    }
}
```

And then where you are using: -

```
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
```

I would use [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to get individual attributes, and then create an `ArrayList<Flight>`, and add `Flight` instance to it: -

```
List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     String[] attributes = line.split(";");
     flights.add(new Flight(attributes));
}
```

**NOTE : -**

You can improve upon how you instantiate your `Flight` class, and how you set different attributes. Since your attributes are of different types, and they are in `String form`, so you would need to use appropriate `conversion` from `String to Integer` or `String to double` which I have not considered here.

Answer (score 0):

I re-iterate the need for a more OO approach but here is what you need for what you asked for.

```
public final class FlightInfoParser {

  private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[]{};

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    List<String> flightNumbersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> originsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> destinationsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> departureTimesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> milesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Double> pricesList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(";");
        flightNumbersList.add(fields[0]);
        originsList.add(fields[1]);
        destinationsList.add(fields[2]);
        departureTimesList.add(fields[3]);
        milesList.add(Integer.parseInt(fields[4]));
        pricesList.add(Double.parseDouble(fields[5]));
    }

    String[] flightNumbersArray = flightNumbersList.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
    String[] originsArray = originsList.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
    String[] destinationsArray = destinationsList.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
    String[] departureTimesArray = departureTimesList.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);

    int[] milesArray = new int[milesList.size()];
    for (int i = 0, len = milesArray.length; i < len; ++i) {
        milesArray[i] = milesList.get(i);
    }

    double[] pricesArray = new double[pricesList.size()];
    for (int i = 0, len = pricesArray.length; i < len; ++i) {
        pricesArray[i] = pricesList.get(i);
    }

  }

}
```